# Should I reply to a non-automated email from the editor acknowledging manuscript submission?

Tags: etiquette, paper-submission, email, editors

Suppose I submit a paper to a journal which does not use an electronic submission system, so I just e-mail it to an editor.

When I receive an e-mail acknowledging the submission (no personalisation beyond [insert my name] and [insert the name of the paper] kind, but it seems not to be automated in any way except perhaps copy-and-paste), should I reply to it (to say thank you), or is it more courteous/established to just not reply?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think there is any particular reason to write back, unless the editor sends a more personalized message or actually asks a question.  However, a quick note back will not be a problem either.